# The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com'

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the FaceBook C# SDK for the first time.

Since I have a simple application I want to create I have picked up the sample Azure MVC application and modified it to point at my facebook application instance and secret as per the configuraiton guidance.

I want to retrieve a months status messages so I need authorisation which has worked thanks to CanvasAuthorize(Perms = "user_about_me") attribute.

However now when I goto the about view I get an error in the controller first:
dynamic result = fbApp.Get("me");

The actual error is listed as:
The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com'

Can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks,

_David

Answer (score 8):

That sounds like a temporary connectivity issue. The server (or your computer) is having trouble resolving http://graph.facebook.com. Try to going to http://graph.facebook.com/microsoft in your browser and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct fb_key and fb_secret values. In my case I have added them in the web config file but when I read the values I have given a wrong name to retrieve. client_id and client_secret values were not set. As a result this error popped out.